# How to remove an item in a file in C but keep the formatting?

Tags: c

Newbie in C here. I'm working on a project that allows the user to create a to-do-list, where they can add and remove items from the list. Code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int row;
void Welcome();
void Add(row, LIST);
void Del(row, LIST);
void write();
int main()
{
   int i, j, finalrow;
   char choice;
   Welcome();
   char LIST[row][100];
   for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
       printf("%d.", i+1);
       scanf("%s", &LIST[i]);
   }
   write(row,LIST);
   do{
       printf("Your todolist is updated! Check it out!\n");
       printf("Wish to add item? Press A\nWish to delete item? Press D\nCool with it? Press Q\nChoice : ");
       scanf("%s", &choice);
       if(choice == 'A'){
           Add(row, LIST);
       } else if(choice == 'D'){
           Del(row, LIST);
       }
   } while (choice != 'Q');
}

void Welcome(){
    printf("Welcome to TO DO List Application\n");
    printf("How many item do you wish to add?\nItems: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
}

void Add(int row, char TOTALLIST[row][100]){
        int newrow, j;
        printf("How many item do you wish to add?\nItems: ");
        scanf("%d", &newrow);
        char NEWLIST[newrow][100];
    
        for(j = 0; j < newrow; j++){
            printf("%d.", j+1);
            scanf("%s", &NEWLIST[j]);
            strcpy(TOTALLIST[row], NEWLIST[j]);
            row++;
        }
        write(row, TOTALLIST);
}

void Del(int row, char TOTALLIST[row][100]){ 
       int delline, i;
       printf("Which item do you wish to delete?\nRow no.: ");
       scanf("%d", &delline);      
       for(i = (delline - 1); i < (row - 1); i++){
           strcpy(TOTALLIST[i],TOTALLIST[(i+1)]);
        }
        row--;
        write(row, TOTALLIST);
}

void write(int row, char LIST[row][100]){
    int j;
   FILE *list;
   list = fopen("TODOLIST.txt","w");
   fprintf(list,"------------TO DO LIST------------\n");
   for(j = 0; j < row; j++){
       fprintf(list, "%d.", j+1);
       fprintf(list, "%s\n", LIST[j]);
   }
}
```

I have seen ways to remove item in array and how to do it in input output file as well. I have tried creating 2 files to do the removing, but as soon as I remove the line the user don't want, the numbering change. Eg.

```
1. do laundry
2. assignments
```

Let's say the user removes item no.1, the output will be:

```
2. assignments
```

That was why I switched to this method, removing items in my char array then write it into the file, unlike the examples I have seen on internet (not sure if I'm not C99 compatible because I'm using Dev C++), the output turns out to be:

```
(remove no.1)
1. assignments
2. assignments
```

And if I throw in more than 2 items, it just becomes:

```
1.ÀúlHù
2.^rhHù
3.^rhHù
```

(p.s.: this project is not finalized yet, I know there's still alot of flaws)

Comment: Tha basic idea should be: 1) open the file, read all of it into memory, close 2) change the in-memory data (add, delete, edit, ...) 3) open the same file truncating it, write data and close the file

Comment: Always check the return value from `scanf`. And.. `scanf("%s", ...` is an absolute "no go". At least do `scanf("%99s",` but better: Use `fgets`.

Comment: Read about `malloc` (and `free`) and use it. Allocation of arrays in stack is bad idea and variable size array is another bad idea. This is C, not Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of problems in your code including undefined behaviors.

The declarations

> ```
> void Add(row, LIST);
> void Del(row, LIST);
> ```

are invalid and cannot compile/aren't compatible with definitions, you want :

```
 void Add(int row, char LIST[row][100]);
 void Del(int row, char LIST[row][100]);
```

or

```
 void Add(int row, char LIST[][100]);
 void Del(int row, char LIST[][100]);
```

or

```
void Add(int row, char (*LIST)[100]);
void Del(int row, char (*LIST)[100]);
```

it is also a bad idea to name local variables/parameter using uppercase, use full uppercase name for macros (#define) to make them visible and to not confuse them with variable/function names

In *main* :

> ```
> scanf("%s", &LIST[i]);
> ```

you have to indicate the address of the array receiving the read line, which is also the address of the first char in the array, so it is not `&LIST[i]` but `LIST[i]`or `&LIST[i][0]`

in the question you have in example the string "do laundry", but your `scanf` allows to read only 'word', it cannot read a string with space(s), for that still using `scanf` you can read a line without the newline doing :

```
scanf(" %[^n]", LIST[i]);
```

notice the space before '%' allowing to bypass the initial spaces including newline coming from previous inputs

but if the user enter more than 99 characters `scanf` will write out of the expected sub array or may be all the array if you read the last string of the array, with an undefined behavior, to avoid that you can do

```
scanf(" %99[^n]", LIST[i]);
```

it is 99 rather than 100 to allow to save the final null char ending the string.

having :

> ```
> char choice;
> ...
> scanf("%s", &choice);
> ```

has undefined behavior because `scanf` will write out of the character in any case (EOF is an int), to also bypass spaces including newline do

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

anyway notice if you enter more than one character (more the newline) the other characters will be available for the next inputs

Note also the variables *j* and *finalrow* are unused, remove them.

In *Add* :

there is the same problem as previously in the line

> ```
> scanf("%s", &NEWLIST[i]);
> ```

abd in fact you do not need at all *NEWLIST* because the goal is to write in *TOTALLIST*, so do not define *NEWLIST* and do directly :

```
scanf(" %99[^n]", TOTALLIST[row]);
```

you need to check you do not enter to much entries in the array, for that you need to know both the max number of row and the number or used row, and *Del* also have to update the needed number of row whose cannot be your variable *row* containing the max number of rows.

In Welcome :

if the user does not enter a valid integer *row* will be silently still 0 (global variable initialization), you will also have a problem if the value is less than 1, you need to check the input starting by the value return by `scanf` :

```
if ((scanf("%d", &row) != 1) || (row < 1)) {
  puts("invalid size, abort");
  exit(-1);
}
```

it is also a bad idea to have *raw* as a global variable, move it local in *main* and give it in argument when necessary, so *Welcome* can return the size:

```
int Welcome()
{
  int row;

  printf("Welcome to TO DO List Application\n"
     "How many item do you wish to add?\nItems: ");
  if ((scanf("%d", &row) != 1) || (row < 1)) {
    puts("invalid size, abort");
    exit(-1);
  }

  return row;
}
```

(not also the right type for a size is not `int` but `size_t` which can correspond to an `unsigned int`)

In Del:

you need to check the validity of the input number, including to check it is not greater than the number of row, and of course updating the used number of row

In Write:

you need to close the file at the end, and also to check you was able to open it

you need also to write the used number of row rather than the max possible

---

A first proposal to do can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Welcome();
void Add(const int row, int * used_row, char list[][100]);
void Del(const int row, int * used_row, char list[][100]);
void Write(int used_row, char list[][100]);

int main()
{
   int row = Welcome();
   char list[row][100];
   int used_row;
     
   for(used_row = 0; used_row < row; used_row++){
     printf("%d.", used_row+1);
     if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", list[used_row]) != 1) {
       puts("EOF, abort");
       exit(-1);
     }
   }
   
   Write(used_row, list);
   
   char choice;
   
   do {
     printf("Your todolist is updated! Check it out!\n"
            "Wish to add item? Press A\n"
            "Wish to delete item? Press D\n"
            "Cool with it? Press Q\nChoice : ");
     if (scanf(" %c", &choice) != 1) {
       puts("EOF, abort");
       exit(-1);
     }
     if(choice == 'A') {
       Add(row, &used_row, list);
     } else if(choice == 'D') {
       Del(row, &used_row, list);
     }
   } while (choice != 'Q');
}

int Welcome()
{
  int row;
  
  printf("Welcome to TO DO List Application\n"
         "How many item do you wish to add?\nItems: ");
  if ((scanf("%d", &row) != 1) || (row < 1)) {
    puts("invalid size, abort");
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  return row;
}

void Add(const int row, int * used_row, char list[][100]){
  int newrow, j;
  
  printf("How many item do you wish to add?\nItems: ");
  if ((scanf("%d", &newrow) != 1) || (newrow < 0)) {
    puts("invalid number");
  }
  else if ((*used_row + newrow) > row) {
    puts("not enough place");
  }
  else if (newrow != 0) {
    for (j = 0; j < newrow; j++) {
      printf("%d.", j+1);
      if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", list[*used_row]) != 1) {
        puts("EOF, abort");
        exit(-1);
      }
      *used_row += 1;
    }
    
    Write(*used_row, list);
  }
}

void Del(int row, int * used_row, char list[][100]){ 
  int delline;
  
  printf("Which item do you wish to delete?\nRow no.: ");
  if ((scanf("%d", &delline) != 1) || (delline <= 0)) {
    puts("invalid rank");
  }
  else if (delline > *used_row) {
    puts("there are less elements");
  }
  else {
    int i;
    
    for (i = (delline - 1); i < (*used_row - 1); i++) {
      strcpy(list[i],list[i+1]);
    }
    *used_row -= 1;
    Write(*used_row, list);
  }
}

void Write(int used_row, char list[][100]){
  int j;
  FILE * fp = fopen("TODOLIST.txt","w");
  
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("cannot open TODOlist.txt");
  }
  else {
    fputs("------------TO DO list------------\n", fp);
    for(j = 0; j < used_row; j++) {
      fprintf(fp, "%d.%s\n", j+1, list[j]);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall -g c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Welcome to TO DO List Application
How many item do you wish to add?
Items: 3
1.do laundry
2.assignments
3.finish to correct your program
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : ^Z
[2]+  Stoppé                 ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat TODOLIST.txt 
------------TO DO list------------
1.do laundry
2.assignments
3.finish to correct your program
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ fg
./a.out
A
How many item do you wish to add?
Items: 0
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : A
How many item do you wish to add?
Items: 1
not enough place
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : D
Which item do you wish to delete?
Row no.: 0
invalid rank
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : D
Which item do you wish to delete?
Row no.: 4
there are less elements
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : D
Which item do you wish to delete?
Row no.: 2
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : ^Z
[2]+  Stoppé                 ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat TODOLIST.txt 
------------TO DO list------------
1.do laundry
2.finish to correct your program
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ fg
./a.out
A
How many item do you wish to add?
Items: 2
not enough place
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : A
How many item do you wish to add?
Items: 1
1.something
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : ^Z
[2]+  Stoppé                 ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat TODOLIST.txt 
------------TO DO list------------
1.do laundry
2.finish to correct your program
3.something
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ fg
./a.out
D
Which item do you wish to delete?
Row no.: 2
Your todolist is updated! Check it out!
Wish to add item? Press A
Wish to delete item? Press D
Cool with it? Press Q
Choice : Q
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat TODOLIST.txt 
------------TO DO list------------
1.do laundry
2.something
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note doing that way there are two limitations :

- each element in the todo list is smaller than 99 (out of the final null character)
- you cannot have more elements than the initial size

Both of there limitations can be removed using dynamic allocations, the array being an array of pointers to char (`char **`) , and that array can be resized using `realloc`. Of course when an entry is deleted it is needed to free it, and added entries must be a new string whose can be read and made using `getline` or the modifier *m* using `scanf`

---

As it is mentioned in a remark of @Yunnosch you can refer to [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for other hints about `scanf`

Comment: @4386427 yes, I am still editing my answer and I was speaking about that

Comment: @4386427 I will propose a solution with fixed array as the OP use and the malloc/realloc

Comment: @4386427 yes there are lot of issues, I save periodically my answer because sometimes I have a problem and loose all, I do not like ^^

Comment: Are you aware of http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html ?

Comment: @Yunnosch what do you mean ?

Comment: Roughly half of your answer is discussing using scanf(). I find the article I linked very helpful on that topic and thought that you can use it to focus on the file handling. I meant it in a purely constructive way.

Comment: "ANSWER ON GOING, PLEASE WAIT I FINISH ..." - Is the answer finished? You didn't edited for roughly 20 minutes.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio not yet, there are a lot of things to say ... and I am also buzy out of that, please wait ...

Comment: @bruno Just wanted to ask. ;-)

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio not a problem ^^

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio done, except if I have the courage to put a full second proposal using dynamic allocations ^^

Comment: @4386427 done, except if I have the courage to put a full second proposal using dynamic allocations rather than to just speak about as I did ^^

Comment: At least to double ping two users in a comment is a feature, I personally would like to have very much and would be very useful for example in such cases.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio yes agree, did you speak about that in "meta" ?

Comment: @bruno Not yet. But definitely worth it. I will try to raise a post when I got time to.

Comment: @Yunnosch I added your link in my answer, thank you for it

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove an item in a file in C but keep the formatting?

### This is not easy.

Files are sequence of bytes, and the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) does not define any way to *insert* or *delete* bytes in the middle of a file (some valid `FILE*` handle from [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)).

Using a database library (such as [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/)) is probably a simpler way to achieve your goals. Or an indexed file library such as [Tokyo Cabinet](https://dbmx.net/tokyocabinet/) or the newer [Tkrzw](https://dbmx.net/tkrzw/). Or use a database server such as [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) or [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB).

Otherwise, use some [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) to read your entire textual file in memory, and dump it into another file.

Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) (also perhaps the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf)) and the documentation of *every* [standard C function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) used in your program. Remember to handle failure and error cases.